# Can you groupby a pandas dataframe giving lists of start and end ranges for a specific column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

start_list = [1, 10, 20, 30]

end_list = [10, 20, 30, 40]

The data has columns including 'Measure', which ranges from 0 to 100. How can you create groups by using the start and end ranges (inclusive)?

Comment: What does your input data look like and expected output from this input data?

Comment: You want start inclusive or end inclusive?   You should have both or you'll double count 10, 20, 30 values.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must use from cut method

```py
df['category']=pd.cut(df, start_list)
```

for more customization, read below

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html